# Font Awesome icon is not appearing in react application

Tags: reactjs, fonts, font-awesome

```
I Install all 3 required modules in react app.
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome

I am trying to add font awesome icon in my program. But it is not showing up.Do I need to copy Font Awesome link and add in my app. That's what I used to do it in my html program.
```

(For example )

But in react how to do it? I tried the way which is in the document but it is not working. I only added the part of my program.Please help.

```
import React  from 'react';
import { Form, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './ContactUs.css';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faCheckSquare, faShare} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faShare)

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
// import { faShare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

class ContactUs extends React.Component{
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
               <Button className="btn send-button mt-4"> 
                  SUBMIT
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="share" />
                  </Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default  ContactUs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any issue except one thing.
As you are using individual icon instead of, `<FontAwesomeIcon icon="share" />` you must use write like this
`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShare} />`

Please check the below link for reference.
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-glade-9ful6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried <FontAwesomeIcon icon={share} /> Error coming says Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 83:42:  'share' is not defined

Comment: You don't need `library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faShare)` this line and all the imports should be on top. There shouldn't be any other code between imports. Make sure you follow this.

Comment: same error occurring share is not defined.

Comment: let me check sandbox

Comment: Ok Got it   <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShare} /> instead of <FontAwesomeIcon icon={share} />

Comment: If I need to use icons in other react pages / file then do I need to import font awesome library again in that page? Also If I want to add some other icons then I will need library